# Java/Android Edittext.gettext().toString not working

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i have one edittext and button.first time my edittext.settext is 1.now i try to check if edidtext.gettext().toString.equels some values do somethink

```
    public class StradaMenuResultReadMore extends Fragment {

public static ImageView buy_btn;

private EditText price_counter;

int av;
private String counterString;

@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_menu_result_loadmore,
            container, false);

    buy_btn = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.strada_buy_btn);
    price_counter = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.strada_price_counter);

    price_counter.setText("1");
    counterString = price_counter.getText().toString();
    av = Integer.parseInt(counterString);

    buy_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (counterString.equals("1")) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else

            {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }

        }
    });

    return rootView;

}
```

at the moment my code working complitly,but if i change edittext input value and then click button,then my code not working
how i can solve my problem?

Comment: Explain how it is not working.

Comment: for example.if i input 5  then toast message is again "one"

Comment: Why is the `ImageView` static?

Comment: Put `counterString = price_counter.getText().toString();` inside `onClick`. Just realized it was in a fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onClick` you need to get the value from the EditText, since `counterString` still contains the old value "1":

```
buy_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counterString = price_counter.getText().toString();
        ....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
counterString = price_counter.getText().toString();
```

Put this line inside onClick

Answer (score 0):

Since `oncreateView()` is called between `onCreate(Bundle)` and `onActivityCreated(Bundle)`, it's called only once and your string is that you are using to compare always remains 1. Hence the issue.
Change this :

```
buy_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        counterString = price_counter.getText().toString();

        if (counterString.equals("1")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
});
```